# Determine When App Receives ANY User Interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iphone app and I am trying to perform an action when the user interacts with the phone in any way. E.g. I am fading out some user interface elements (buttons) and I only want them to show when the user tries to do something. E.g. in android there is a method called onUserInteraction.

I have tried just overriding touchesBegan in my UIViewController, but this seems to only be called sporadically. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you can elaborate your question then that will be easier to understand your point. I mean what kind of operation you want to perform on interaction? There are few methods in Objective C which can be called when your App activates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UIWindow` and override the `sendEvent:` method:

```
@interface MyAppWindow : UIWindow {}
@end

@implementation MyAppWindow

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   //do something to wake up your app here...     
   [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end

@interface MyAppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate {
    MyAppWindow *window;
}
//blah blah blah
```

See the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW3).

Comment: `sendEvent` gets the accelerometer events, too, for free?

Comment: @Yar I think so, if not you can use a `UIGestureRecognizer` for that.

Comment: This worked well, but its kind of messy to have to pass the view controller back to the window.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob Relkin... of course OP wanted touch gestures only.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't give accelerometer events.